# Get Log.d() output from app user

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

My code is littered with `Log.g()` calls for my own debugging purposes, which I use `Proguard` to [remove on release](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#logging).

One particular user is experiencing performance issues I'm unable to track down by other means, and I would really benefit from seeing the `Log.d()` output that results running the app on their device.

So is there an easy way of obtaining this output from the user, without requiring their device to be rooted, and without having to put them through the trouble of any ugly hacks or installing third party apps they might be wary of?

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways for tracking log from clients.

- If there is a crash you'll see stack trace in GooglePlay Developer console: https://play.google.com/apps/publish
- You may use some bug report libraries ex: Applause http://www.applause.com/mobile-sdk, Crashlytics https://try.crashlytics.com, Instabug https://instabug.com
- You may write your own mechanism to send log but it requires to have logging server implementation on Your side.
- If it's beta user, he may connect phone to LogCat without root permissions if You send him debuggable version of application.

Otherwise if app have removed by Proguard all logs, app has *debuggable=false* and Your client doesn't want to install provided by You debbugable version of appliaction it's is impossible to get same log as You have in Your debuggable version.